# Is finding a direction in which the limit of the function tends to infinity enough to prove that the limit doesn't exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

For this given limit:

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^4}$

I was able to determine a direction in which this limit tends to infinity. This direction is given by:
$ x^2 =y^7-y^4$

However, this limit is equal to $0$. My question is: if we find a path in which the limit diverges why can't we say that the limit doesn't exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That direction that you have mention doesn't make sense: of $y\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$, then $y^7-y^4<0$.

And the limit is $0$ because, whenever $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, $0\leqslant\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}\leqslant y^2$; in particular, that function is bounded near $(0,0)$, and therefore there is no path passing through $(0,0)$ such that the limit along that path is $\infty$.

Comment: I corrected my question

Comment: *How* is that correction is better than the original version? If $y\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$, then $y^7-y^4<0$, and therefore the equality $x^2=y^7-y^4$ makes no sense.